# String Boot query brings empty entity for existing data

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have this Spring Boot app and I have a profile entity, and I have my repository.

The problem is that when I do the second query for some profile by email the object returns as not null, but there is no data in it, so I cannot compare data for this object.

My repository:

```
public interface ProfileRepository extends JpaRepository<Profile, Long> {

    Profile findById(Long id);

    @Query("select e from Profile e where e.email = ?1")
    Profile findByEmail(String email);
}
```

Code to execute those queries:

```
Profile myProfile = this.profileRepository.findById(data.getIdMyProfile());
Profile hisProfile = this.profileRepository.findByEmail(data.getEmail()); // see this one on the image - here is the problem        
Card myCard = this.cardRepository.findById(data.getIdMyCard());
```

[image]

I realized that this occurs if I do 2 queries on Profile entity in a row, I inverted the query to see the difference and the second object comes not null but with no data at all.
[image]

Any clue why this problem occurs?

Comment: Try to remove the @query annotation as you don’t need any custom queries just a simple repository retrieval.

Comment: I did remove the @Query annotation, same result, I think is something else because in another method that query works for email.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution, one entity was with **.LAZY** on one of it's properties that pointed to Profile entity (as a child), I changed to **.EAGER** e problem solved:

```
// The owner of this card
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_profile")
private Profile profile;
```